# Lowest value and its associated key in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, twitter, named-entity-recognition

I am trying identify artists from twitter. So I have a tweet and I am using the [natural for node](https://github.com/NaturalNode/natural) to tokenise the tweet and compare it to an array of artists using Levenshtein distance to match the token with the artists. My problem is that I am having difficulty in the logic of actually comparing each token to the list of artists and matching the one the tweet is referring to.

The following example should get Clean Bandit as the artist.

```
var saturday = ["Kanye West", "Pharrell Williams", "Paloma Faith", "Burt Bacharach", "Clean Bandit"];

var tweet = "My queen @graciechatto about to go on The Other Stage at Glastonbury #cleanbandit #glastonbury…"

tokenizer = new natural.WordTokenizer(); //new tokeniser

var tweetTokenised = tokenizer.tokenize(tweet); //tokenise the tweet and store it in tweetTokenised

var i , j;

//loop through tokenised tweet    
for(i=0;i<tweetTokenised.length;i++){
    console.log(tweetTokenised[i] + "--------------------------");
    var temp = [];

    //compare token with list of artists performing on saturday    
    for(j=0;j<saturday.length;j++){

        //remove whitespace from the tweet tokens
        console.log(tweetTokenised[i]+ "--->"+saturday[j]); //testing purposes
        var score = natural.LevenshteinDistance(tweetTokenised[i].replace(/\s+/g, '').toLowerCase(),saturday[j].toLowerCase());

        //store score for each token vs artists in a temp dictionary 
        temp.push({
            key:   saturday[j],
            value: score
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Sort the array by the `score` property, then the first element will have the lowest score.

Comment: thanks @Barmar exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        //sort array from lowest to biggest

        temp.sort(function(a, b) {

            return parseFloat(a.value) - parseFloat(b.value);

        });





        //console.log(temp);

        //get the first object (the smallest in this instance as its been sorted)

        lowest = temp.shift();

        console.log(lowest);

        if(lowest.value < 2){

            distances.push(lowest);

        }

    }

    console.log("printing distances");

    console.log(distances[0].key); //get artist name 

}
```